# Change component place each route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I want to change rendered component place each time the route (url) changes.
e.g. I have 3 blocks: Home, Works, Contacts. When url is site.com/home the content renders in Home block, when url is site.com/works the content moves to Works block and so on.

I did a kind of what I want but it renders the whole page when It seems more optimal to just moves new content.
So can you suggest better decisions?

The whole project you can get and run locally from here: https://github.com/g1un/reactjs-site

What it looks like (buggy regarding routing) you can see here: http://g1un.ru/reactjs/

I paste the main files below.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import style from './../scss/style.scss';

import { Header } from './components/Header';
import { About } from './components/About';
import { Works } from './components/Works';
import { Contacts } from './components/Contacts';
import { NotFound } from './components/NotFound';

class App extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="container">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={About}/>
                    <Route exact path="/works" component={Works}/>
                    <Route exact path="/contacts" component={Contacts}/>
                    <Route component={NotFound}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
}

render(<App />, window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

**About.js (Works.js, Contacts.js are similar)**

```
import React from 'react';
import DocumentTitle from 'react-document-title';

import { Header } from './Header';

export class About extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <DocumentTitle title='About'>
            <Header currentPath={this.props.location.pathname}>
                <h1>
                    About
                </h1>
            </Header>
        </DocumentTitle>
    );
}
}
```

**Header.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const PATHS = ['/', '/works', '/contacts'];
const PAGES = ['About', 'Works', 'Contacts'];

import { HeaderItem } from './HeaderItem';

export class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.currentPath = props.currentPath;
        this.content = props.children;
        this.paths = PATHS;
        this.pages = PAGES;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <header className="header">
                <nav className="nav">
                    <div className="nav__list">
                        {this.paths.map((path, i) => {
                            return <HeaderItem key={i} currentPath={path} currentPage={this.pages[i]} pageContent={path === this.currentPath ? this.content : ''}/>;
                        })}
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

**HeaderItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

export class HeaderItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"nav__item " + (this.props.pageContent ? "_active" : "")}>
                <NavLink className="nav__link" exact activeClassName="_active" to={this.props.currentPath}>
                    {this.props.currentPage}
                </NavLink>
                {this.props.pageContent ? <div className="nav__content content">{this.props.pageContent}</div> : ''}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you can improve one part, instead of rendering Header and HeaderItem inside each page (each time a new instance will get created), better to render them inside App component, because that will be fixed part, by that way each time it will replace only the page component, and re-render the Header (not create new instance of Header).

Comment: @MayankShukla I agree with you, best to call Header just once. Other than that small detail, all looks fine to me!

Comment: But how will rendered content moves from one block to another?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the desicion myself.
The fact is that I can't use any blocks inside `<Switch/>`, so I've simply used `<Route>`s without `<Switch/>`, putting them in any blocks I need.
And for '404' page I've created `<Switch/>` block with same Routes inside without component attributes except one for '404' page.
Now in each HeaderItem I can control whether its content is visible or not.

New index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import DocumentTitle from 'react-document-title';

import style from './../scss/style.scss';

import { Header } from './components/Header';
import { HeaderItem } from './components/HeaderItem';
import { About } from './components/About';
import { Works } from './components/Works';
import { Contacts } from './components/Contacts';
import { NotFound } from './components/NotFound';

const PATHS = ['/', '/works', '/contacts'];
const PAGES = ['About', 'Works', 'Contacts'];
const COMPONENTS = [About, Works, Contacts];

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.paths = PATHS;
        this.pages = PAGES;
        this.components = COMPONENTS;
        this.state = {
            documentTitle: this.getDocumentTitle()
        };
    }

    updateDocumentTitle(pageTitle) {
        if(this.state.documentTitle === pageTitle) return;
        this.setState({
            documentTitle: this.getDocumentTitle()
        });
    }

    getDocumentTitle() {
        let pathIndex = this.paths.indexOf(window.location.pathname);
        if(pathIndex === -1) {
            return 'Not found';
        } else {
            return this.pages[pathIndex];
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DocumentTitle title={this.state.documentTitle}>
                <Router>
                    <div className="container">
                        <Switch>
                            {this.paths.map((path, i) => {
                                return <Route key={i} exact path={path}/>;
                            })}
                            <Route render={() => <NotFound text="Error 404"/>}/>
                        </Switch>
                        <Header>
                            {this.paths.map((path, i) => {
                                return (
                                    <HeaderItem
                                        key={i}
                                        routePath={path}
                                        pageTitle={this.pages[i]}
                                        updateDocumentTitle={this.updateDocumentTitle.bind(this)}
                                    >
                                        <Route exact path={path} component={this.components[i]}/>
                                    </HeaderItem>
                                );
                            })}
                        </Header>
                        <Switch>
                            {this.paths.map((path, i) => {
                                return <Route key={i} exact path={path}/>;
                            })}
                            <Route render={() => <NotFound text="Page not found"/>}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </DocumentTitle>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

New HeaderItem.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Content } from './Content';
import { About } from './About';
import { Works } from './Works';
import { Contacts } from './Contacts';

const COMPONENTS = [About, Works, Contacts];
const PAGES = ['About', 'Works', 'Contacts'];

export class HeaderItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.path = props.routePath;
        this.content = props.children;
        this.page = props.pageTitle;
        this.components = COMPONENTS;
        this.pages = PAGES;
        this.index = this.pages.indexOf(this.page);
        this.updateDocumentTitle = props.updateDocumentTitle;

        this.state = {
            isActive: this.path === window.location.pathname
        };
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
        //to change page title if this component is active
        if(this.path === window.location.pathname) {
            this.updateDocumentTitle(this.page);
        }
        this.saveRouteComponent();
    }

    isActive() {
        return this.path === window.location.pathname;
    }

    saveRouteComponent() {
        if(this.state.isActive || this.path !== window.location.pathname) return;
        //once opened route get 'isActive' state and its content will not removed when this route is deactivated
        this.setState({ isActive: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"nav__item " + (this.isActive() ? "_active" : "")}>
                <div className="nav__item-wrapper">
                    <NavLink className="nav__link" exact activeClassName="_active" to={this.path}>
                        {this.page}
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
                {(this.isActive() || this.state.isActive) ? <div className="nav__content"><Content pageTitle={this.page}>{this.state.isActive ? React.createElement(this.components[this.index]) : this.content}</Content></div> : ''}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```